# how to list the partition, which are minimum 50% of them are used

Tags: linux, shell-script, debian, shell, fedora

Hello dear professionals,

I am just trying to learn Linux and I get often problem.
I am trying to list the partitions, which are minimum 50% used. I've tried **`sfdisk`**, but don't know how to pip it further.

**Please help me!**

thanks a lot for your gently feedback and help.

Comment: Please clarify whether the goal is to see **all** partitions with more than 50% usage, or only the *mounted* partitions  with more than 50% usage.

Comment: could be called also monitoring!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df -h -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs |  awk '{$1=$1};1' | awk '/dev/ && $5 > 50'
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. would you mind explain a bit your code, please?

Comment: Of course (df -- display free disk space)  
  
    `df -h -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs`  
-h ommits temporary filesystems  
  
    `awk '{$1=$1};1'`  
trims white chars  
  
    `awk '/dev/ && $5 > 50'`  
/dev/ like grep matching lines with `dev` string  
$5 - fifth column

Comment: You can run commands: `df -h -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs` next `df -h -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs |  awk '{$1=$1};1'` to show step by step what's happen

Comment: Doesn't this only list _mounted_ partitions on `/dev/`?

Comment: @agc As i wrote before, try to run commands step by step according to pipes

Comment: @MarekLisiecki, Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear -- I understood your code already.  My previous comment *"Doesn't this only list mounted partitions on /dev/?"* is a rhetorical question.  It should imply the statement:  this answer fails to list **un**mounted partitions.  As it's currently written the Q. is perhaps broader than the OP intended, since the Q. doesn't necessarily require that *any* of the partitions need to be mounted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below command

```
 df -Ph| awk 'NR>1 {gsub("%","",$(NF-1));print}'|awk '{if($(NF-1)>50){print $0}}'
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply!